# How to iterate list on each user click

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have kept the object into a list. I want to iterate them with user click.
Is there any method like list.next()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is often to just keep a current index stored in a local variable.  On each "click", just increment your index, and use the value in `list[index]`.

You could, potentially, call `list.GetEnumerator()` and use [`IEnumerator.MoveNext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx), but this is more likely to cause issues.  In particular, if your collection is modified between clicks, you'll have problems...

Answer (score 0):

From another post:

```
public void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action) 
{ 
    foreach (var item in items) 
        action(item); 
}
```

Call it like this:

```
ForEach(myList, i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Comment: i think he meant 'iterate' as 'move forward one'